# Convert SQL based application to Redis

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nosql, redis

I have a MS SQL based application, which main goal is to search through a table of companies. 
This company table has several columns on which one could search. Like CompanyName, Address, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude.

Now, because of the need for speed, i'm thinking of converting this to a Redis DB based application. Can anyone help me with which approach to take to do this properly? How should i setup my Redis DB? And how should i query it to find all companies with *tech* in their company name and located between lat x-0.5 and lat x+0.5 and long y-0.5 and long y+0.5?

Or is Redis perhaps not the best NOSQL db to use for this type or searching? Other recommendations are welcome too.

Comment: Redis is a key/value store. Searching by values is the one thing it was **not** made for.

Comment: Converting an application to a database technology with a different philosophy rarely ends well, because to really use the strengths of the new database you often have to completely reconsider the way you structure your data. This might also affects lots of seemingly unrelated aspects of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a key/value store which is very fast when you know the exact key, but it is very bad at searching multiple keys for a specific value or range of values. So I would not advise you to use Redis.

When you want to search by GPS coordinates, [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) would be an option, because [it has a rich API especially for geospatial searching](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/).

When you need fast and feature-rich full-text search, you should take a look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), which is not a database itself but a tool to integrate with other databases.

By the way: The mantra "NoSQL is fast" is a gross oversimplification. It is true that specific databases can perform specific tasks under specific premises a lot faster than any relational database, but there are also cases where the opposite is the case.

Are you really sure that you already used all possibilities to improve the performance of your MSSQL database?

- Does every search you do use an appropriate index?
- Are all JOINs you make on explicit secondary keys?
- Is your database properly normalized?
- Could you avoid some expensive operations by refactoring your database design, even when it means that you need to break normalization?

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand. In the meanwhile i'd already figured that Redis might not be what i need, but it's still good to hear that from someone else.